# How do i fill a column with specific fixed value for a table using select

Tags: psql

I want to select some data, but that data has a column that has `NULL` values. I want it to change it from null to a specific fixed value without changing the database

i.e.
**V_fruits**

```
number | fruit     | three
1      | apple     | <null>
2      | pinapple  | <null>
3      | grape     | <null>
4      | lemon     | <null>
```

I want it using

```
Select "number","fruit",case when "three" is null then three='ofcourse'  from  V_fruits
```

I want some guidance on this please it is `Psql`

**Expected**
**V_fruits**

```
number fruit      three
1      apple      Of course
2      pinapple   Of course
3      grape      Of course
4      lemon      Of course
```

**Obtained
V_fruits**

```
number  fruit    three
1       apple    false
2       pinapple false
3       grape    false
4       lemon    false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead:

```
Select "number","fruit",case when "three" is null then 'ofcourse' END  from  V_fruits
```

The difference here is that `three='ofcourse'` is evaluated and returns `false` because `three` is null, therefore it can't be `'ofcourse'`.

Optionally you could use:

```
SELECT "number", "fruit", COALESCE(three, 'ofcourse') FROM v_fruits;
```